# How can I can a mock an external class using jest?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I currently have the following Vue page code:

```
<template>
   // Button that when clicked called submit method
</template>

<script>
import { moveTo } from '@/lib/utils';

export default {
  components: {
  },
  data() {
  },
  methods: {
    async submit() {
      moveTo(this, COMPLETE_ACTION.path, null);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

and then I have a test file for this page. My issue is that Im trying to check and assert that the moveTo method is called with the correct parameters using Jest. It keeps showing expected undefined but received an object. Here are the key points from the test file:

```
  import * as dependency from '@/lib/utils';
  dependency.moveTo = jest.fn();
  // I then trigger the button call which calls the submit method on the page
  expect(dependency.moveTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith(this, COMPLETE_ACTION.path, null);
```

Im unsure what **this** is in this context and what I should actually be passing in. Just to note I am using the mount helper from vue test utils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue and it was the **this** param within the test. *This* was undefined in the test and was expecting to match against a VueComponent.

I used my wrapper and then accessed the VueComponent by referencing the vm property as per the documentation: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#properties

In turn I updated the following line and added **wrapper.vm**

```
  expect(dependency.moveTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith(wrapper.vm, COMPLETE_ACTION.path, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the module itself. In your case you are making an assertion on a spy function that is never called.

You can add a module mock by creating a ["***mocks**/ subdirectory immediately adjacent to the module*"](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks). For a node module ["*If the module you are mocking is a Node module (e.g.: lodash), the mock should be placed in the **mocks** directory adjacent to node_modules*"](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks).

In your case (there are other approaches) you need to create a `__mocks__` folder adjacent to the `node_modules` one and create a file at `__mocks__/lib/utils/index.js` and export the mocked function:

```
    export const moveTo = jest.fn()
```